# Equilibrium composition of methane–water system under given conditions

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, gas-laws

> Calculate the equilibrium composition of a reactive system consisting of an equimolecular mixture of $\ce{CH4}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ at $\pu{900 K}$ and $\pu{1 atm},$ considered to be an ideal mixture of ideal gases. Under these conditions, the equilibrium constants of the two possible reactions are
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{CH4 + H2O &<=> CO + 3 H2} &\quad K_{p,1} &= 1.307 \tag{R1}\\
> \ce{CO + H2O &<=> CO2 + H2}&\quad K_{p,2} &= 2.210 \tag{R2}
> \end{align}
> $$

I have tried to solve it by expressing each $K_{p,i}$ independently, considering there are five constituents in this ideal mixture and that $\ce{CH4}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ are the starting compounds, with $n^0 = 1.$ I associated a different degree of advance, $\xi_i,$ to each of the reactions and solved the two-equation system, but it seems that this is not the proper solution because the reactions are not independent.

Can anybody figure out a solution?

Comment: Editing note: both $K_p$ values had a comma which I interpreted as a decimal separator, but it might as well be a thousands separator. I'm too lazy to look up a plausible $K_p$ value, so please be aware.

Comment: Vandalism is not accepted behaviour even over own posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$moles\ CH_4=1-e_1$$
$$moles\ H_2O=1-(e_1+e_2)$$
$$moles\ CO=e_1-e_2$$
$$moles\ CO_2=e_2$$
$$moles\ H_2=3e_1+e_2$$
where the $e_1$ is the number of moles of $CH_4$ destroyed and $e_2$ the number of moles of $CO_2$ that are produced.

So the equilibrium equations are going to read:$$\frac{(e_1-e_2)(3e_1+e_2)^3}{(1-e_1-e_2)(1-e_1)(2+2e_1)^2}=K_1$$and $$\frac{e_2(3e_1+e_2)}{(e_1-e_2)(1-e_1-e_2)}=K_2$$

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti. This is the start of how to solve it.  I don't want to reveal too much.  What part of this don't you understand?

Comment: Ok I see, you are giving a hint answer. I think you should change the wording of `number of times each of the two reactions has been executed`, I had to read it a couple of times to understand. Maybe change it to `extent of reaction` or something like that. Also, hint answers are discouraged nowadays: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/hint-answers-revisited

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti OK, I changed the wording to make things clearer.

Comment: The reactions don't each have separate numbers of moles in the denominator to get the mole fractions for each.  The total number of moles for both reactions is $(2+2e_1)$.  And, the two equations are coupled, so  you must solve these two non-linear algebraic equations simultaneously.

Comment: –1 for improper notations and terms like "$moles\ CH_4$", "*number of moles*" and also, this is a hint, not an answer. Please post suggestions and hints in the comments section shall you decide not to reveal the complete solution.